# Using Delete method to delete substring with special char and numbers in java

Tags: java, regex, stringbuilder

I am trying to write a small functionality to delete the irregular expression that are generated while copying text from old browsers. I have to specifically use `StringBuilder` [`delete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)) method for this.
Below a sample code snippet that I wrote. While it identifies the correct characters its deleting just the next iteration
`

```
    String input = buff.readLine();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9/$&+,:;=?@#/]");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
                while(m.find()){

                    sb.delete(m.start(), m.end());
                }



            System.out.println("Formatted content\n"+sb);
//input: this is &^4567 matcher
//expected output: this is matcher
//output: this is ^46 acher
```

`

Comment: Why not just use `replaceAll`? `input = input.replaceAll("[0-9/$&+,:;=?@#/]+", "");`?

Comment: After something has been deleted, the indexes become jumbled up, because StringBuilder contents change, while Matcher contents do not. So the next iteration will not work as you might expect. You might want to collect all matches first, and only then delete.

Comment: You're also missing `^` from your regex

Comment: Yep thanks. Noted that :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you have removed one character from the string buffer, the index available with matcher are no longer accurate. You can verify this by printing out the string before and after the call to sb.delete...
Add following line of code after sb.delete() to fix it.This will ensure that matcher searched for pattern again  and has the correctr indices.

```
 m = p.matcher(sb);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked to delete them in correct sequence. However there are still the spaces left by it that need to be appended.

Comment: use the below pattern to fix that  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\^0-9/$&+,:;=?@#/] *"); .  * means 0 or more occurance of previous character, thus will handle spaces as well.